# Button in the bottom of all pages to return back to table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, hyperlink, button, backref

As the title said, I want to obtain Somthing like this, a button that send me back to the

> toc :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might get you started. Just replace `example-image` with an image file of your button:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for dummy contents
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
 \AddToShipoutPicture{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \node [rectangle, anchor=center, yshift=2cm] 
 (box\thepage) at 
 (current page.south){\hyperlink{mytableofcontents}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\phantomsection 
\hypertarget{mytableofcontents}{}
\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly ! I appreciate so much your help. 

This communauty is amazing !